# Failed to load steamui.so

Tags: steam

I tried to load `steamui.so`, but got this error message trace:

```
[2018-11-01 03:39:38] BCommitUpdatedFiles: failed to create directory ./steam/cached
[2018-11-01 03:39:38] BCommitUpdatedFiles: failed to process ./steam
[2018-11-01 03:39:38] Failed to apply update, reverting...
[2018-11-01 03:39:38] Verifying installation...
[2018-11-01 03:39:38] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2018-11-01 03:39:38] Unable to read and verify install manifest /home/ulaankhuu/.local/share/Steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12.installed
[2018-11-01 03:39:38] Verification complete
[2018-11-01 03:39:38] Downloading update...
[2018-11-01 03:39:38] Checking for available updates...
[2018-11-01 03:39:39] Download complete.
[2018-11-01 03:39:39] Extracting package...
[2018-11-01 03:39:59] Installing update...
[2018-11-01 03:40:01] BCommitUpdatedFiles: failed to create directory ./steam/cached
[2018-11-01 03:40:01] BCommitUpdatedFiles: failed to process ./steam
[2018-11-01 03:40:01] Failed to apply update, reverting...
[2018-11-01 03:40:05] Shutdown
```

How can I fix it?